# Python Py to EXE

Tags: python, pip, exe, pyinstaller

Trying to figure out why Pyinstaller does not make the .EXE in the \Dist folder.

What i'm running is `pyinstaller --onefile FileName.py`

But after this it fails:

> 7758 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) An error occurred, traceback follows:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe__main__.py", line 269, in convert
>       pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 111, in run
>       run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
>       PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
>       build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
>       exec(code, spec_namespace)
>     File "C:\Users\Marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2gf7vp4s\File_Rename.spec", line 18, in 
>       pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 98, in **init**
>       self.**postinit**()
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in **postinit**
>       self.assemble()
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 128, in assemble
>       self.code_dict = {
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 129, in 
>       key: strip_paths_in_code(code)
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 652, in strip_paths_in_code
>       consts = tuple(
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 653, in 
>       strip_paths_in_code(const_co, new_filename)
>     File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 660, in strip_paths_in_code
>       return code_func(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize,
>   TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

And so on.

- Path is set
- Newest versions
- Script is working as intended when run through Python

The idea is to make the .py an .exe so i can run it on a computer that does not have Python.

Comment: you might wanna consider creating a virtual environment for your project and then try installing it. And I suppose you wrote in your question the `Pyinstaller`, the `P` in block letters, it should be `p`. I guess that's a typo you made.

Comment: Hi. I did try to use an virtual environment but it seems the end result is the same. And yes i made a type with the "P" , thank you for noticing.

Comment: is behavior any different when not using --onefile? Maybe this can help guide to the cause. Also, looks like you did not copy the entire message, the part that you copied  shows an "INFO", not error?

Comment: Ye i did not copy the full error since its extremely long. And no leaving --onefile away does not change anything. I edited it to the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the answer.

By using `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

it uninstalled the version 3.5 and installed the 4.0 dev version.

Used `pyinstaller xxxx.py` and voilà

Thank you for everyone's participation